# creating folder and subfolder with batch

Tags: batch-file

i am currently trying to create folders with sub folders using a batch file - i used the code below but it is not working - the txt file has a list of the main folders and then the other lines are the sub folders that should be created in every folder.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%* in (jobid.txt) 
do(mkdir 
"C:\joblist\%%*" 
"C:\joblist\%%*\Loss Sheet" 
"C:\joblist\%%*\Authorization" 
"C:\joblist\%%*\Certificate of Satisfaction"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Drying Lobs-Outlines"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Lead Documentation"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Photos"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Waiver of Liability"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Mold Reports-Documentation"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Bank-Mortgage Doc"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Invoice"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Payment-Checks"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Job Costs-Vendors"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Emails"
"C:\joblist\%%*\Notes"
)
```

when i run the batch file nothing happens and no folders are created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /F "delims=" %%a in (jobid.txt) DO (
    FOR  %%x IN (
    "C:\joblist\%%a"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Loss Sheet"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Authorization"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Certificate of Satisfaction"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Drying Lobs-Outlines"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Lead Documentation"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Photos"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Waiver of Liability"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Mold Reports-Documentation"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Bank-Mortgage Doc"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Invoice"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Payment-Checks"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Job Costs-Vendors"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Emails"
    "C:\joblist\%%a\Notes"
    ) DO (
    ECHO MD "%%~x"
    )
)
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo` before `MD` if it looks good.

<sub>*Tihs is a nice question, I love it.*</sub>☺

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why throw in a second loop and variable when they're not needed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're understanding the use of the loop variable in your `for`. The `*` has special meaning in a command window (DOS box); it's a wildcard. You also need to repeat the command `mkdir` for every folder, not just the first one.

Try using an actual variable name instead:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (jobid.txt) do (
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*" 
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Loss Sheet" 
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Authorization" 
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Certificate of Satisfaction"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Drying Lobs-Outlines"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Lead Documentation"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Photos"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Waiver of Liability"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Mold Reports-Documentation"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Bank-Mortgage Doc"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Invoice"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Payment-Checks"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Job Costs-Vendors"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Emails"
  mkdir "C:\joblist\%%*\Notes"
)
```

(Just as a note, `md` is shorthand for `mkdir`, so you can replace all of the `mkdir` commands with `md` instead to save three keystrokes per line. Either way works identically, and the longer name might be clearer for future reference.)